# how to implement a list in database

Tags: mysql, list, path

Im developing a carpooling webapp and I need to manage the path for each ride:
a ride may have multiple stops . 
Exemple: Im going from city A to city D going through city B and C. I can pickup only people going to D or i can pick up even people going to C and D make a stop and maybe pickup other people.

I need to store that in MySQL database .
I tried to use linked list like :

```
CREATE TABLE ordered_items (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    city int NOT NULL,
    previous_item_id INT UNSIGNED NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (previous_item_id) REFERENCES ordered_items(item_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (city) REFERENCES cities(id) 
);

CREATE TABLE offers(
       ...

   path INT NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (path) REFERENCES ordered_items(id)
);
```

But im going to have duplicates .
is there any other solution to this?

Comment: Which SQL we are talking about?

Comment: @dropoutcoder I mean MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I think best way to store multiple stops/GPS locations is to use [MySQL Spatial Data Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-type-overview.html) instead (of list) as its purpose is to store geometry or geography points.

Comment: im trying to store cities names